# visual studio configuration type dll: how to turn off lib overwrite?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll, static-libraries

Is it possible to turn off the .lib overwrite when building a dll in VS2010?

I need both the .lib and the .dll, but when i turn the configuration type back to dll, my .lib in the outpufolder gets overwritten by a 1-2KB .lib which is useless for linking in my main project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited after comment**

If you want a dynamic library (creates dll and lib file) and a static library (lib file), you need separate configurations in Visual Studio for building a dynamic library and a static library.

Usually VS provides per default a "Debug" and a "Release" configuration. You could add additionally a "DebugStatic" and a "ReleaseStatic" configuration for your static library.

Per default VS uses the configuration names as output directories, so you would have the following dirs:

```
-project
--Debug
---libraryd.dll
---libraryd.lib
--Release
---library.dll
---library.lib
--DebugStatic
---libraryd.lib
--ReleaseStatic
---library.lib
```

Comment: Yes thats what i need. A dynamic library (dll without lib file) and a static library (lib file). 

1. I set the configuration to static lib and get the lib file.
2. I change the configuration to dynamic library, get the dll and my lib file from the build before is lost. Do i need to seperate the output folders too, or is there any other way?

Comment: As explained, the dynamic library comes always with a dll file and a lib file (which is needed for linking).